# How to calculate the duration of a task in each shift?

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, constraint, constraint-programming, job-shop-scheduling

I am solving a job scheduling problem with three shifts,
the duration of all shifts are assumed to be known (and might be equal):

[image]

- The tasks can start from any shift
- We know the duration of each task in minutes

Some examples:
[image]

- if it starts from minute $1\leq start \leq 480$ then it is in shift1
- if it starts from minute $481\leq start \leq 960$ then it is in shift2
- if it starts from minute $961\leq start \leq 1440$ then it is in shift3

Now the question is how to calculate the duration that falls into each shift depending on the starting minute (variable) and duration (parameter) ?

**Input:**

- Duration of each shift
- Duration of task

**Output:**

I am looking for the values of $h_1,h_2,h_3$ in each case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$h_1, h_2, h_3$ mean the duration time in each period, respectively?
Output also including the start time variables?

Ans:

$h_1 = (480 - start) * b_1$

$h_2 = duration - h_1 - h_3$

$h_3 = (finish - 960) * b_3$

,where $b_1 = 1$ if $start < 480$, otherwise $0$. $b_3 = 1$ if $finish > 960$, otherwise $0$.

PS in your case $b_1$ and $b_3$ can be parameter if start time is given, otherwise should be variables. Furthermore, if you would like to apply to more general setting such as: more than 3 periods that would be very complicated to define.

Comment: Since I don't have reputation enough yet, I put the questions in the answer block. Hop you don't mind it.

Comment: Thank you . I corrected the h2 in blue clock. 
The start time is determined by other constraints so let's assume for a given start time how to calculate the h1,h2,h3

but we have to treat it as a variable

Comment: Another question is the red block, h1 is equal to 400 or 380? if h1 = 380 then h2 would be 120, right?

Comment: Difficult to make too many mistakes but I did it :)

Comment: I put the answer in above. You can check the logic is valid or not. Thanks!

Comment: @ytsao, would you please, explain how these three equations can be feasible for the yellow task in the above picture? The start time is $300$, and the remaining duration in the first shift is 180. Then it occupies the whole of the second shift which is equal to $480$, and the remaining duration in the third shift is $40$. Your first constraint is equal to $180$ (480-300). The third is $40$ (1000-960), and the second would be $780$ (1000-180-40).

Comment: @Optimizationteam, is it the case what you are looking for? (If I am wrong please, correct me).

Comment: @A.Omidi Thanks for your question. The second equation should  be duration time - h1 - h3, instead of finish time.

Comment: @ytsao, thanks. I think this is why in a real situation instead of using a math model to assign tasks in the shifts dynamically, it comes with an RCCP method and explodes the tasks on the resources by a Gantt chart with regard to the break times and other planned shut down times without having any issue to calculation the start and the end time of each task.